# Are Custom Push notifications possible on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, push-notification

I have read at many places that push notification alert cannot be customized...
But was wondering, how are apps like NDTV, "Talking Tom" are able to use custom Notifications ...

I am not an expert in push notification, so if my question is wrong please excuse ...

As I am new member to this group, i am not allowed to upload images ...
The notifications i was mentioning were similar to below:
http://cdn.imore.com/images/stories//2011/10/ios_5_iphone_notification_center_lock_screen_single.png

Thanks..

Comment: Can you give an example (picture, maybe?) of this "custom" notification.

Comment: sample image : http://cdn.imore.com/images/stories//2011/10/ios_5_iphone_notification_center_lock_screen_single.png

Comment: That is the same notification style for all apps. Maybe you were referring to the design change from iOS 4 to iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture your provided is a standard notification in iOS 5. Notifications like this will appear either as an alert, as you showed, or in the Notification Center. There is nothing special you need to do to get your app's icon included in the push. The only thing "custom" here is the content provided within the notification (in the case of your picture, who tweeted and what the tweet was).

Also, judging from the "ROGERS" in the status bar, this could be a jailbroken device, in which case the standard rules don't necessarily apply.

Comment: I can verify that jailbreaking newer iOS versions has been known to mess up notifications, including game center invites.